# ASP.net MVC cookie problem

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, session-cookies

I've got the following code...

```
private readonly string CookieName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CookieName"];

public void AddCookie(HttpContext context)
{
   var uniqueId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

   context.Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie(CookieName, uniqueId));
}
```

So the cookie arrives at the browser with *no* value. Any ideas?

Cheers, Ian.

Answer (score 1):

Are you able to test or refactor the code to use something like this?

```
HttpCookie c = new HttpCookie("foo");
c.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(99);
c.Values[CookieName] = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(c);
```

Comment: Well it did a few times but not anymore!

Comment: One thing it seems to have a problem with is naming the cookie from a variable as opposed to a string literal.

Comment: Oh I've realized the problem. I was reading the cookie from Response instead of Request. It must have been overwriting the value. Gosh what an ignorant fool I've been. Thanks for your help p.campbell.